# Move from catch-all route to specific route

Tags: ruby-on-rails

In a legacy Rails application we have a catch-all route, something like

```
match '/:controller(/:action(/:id))(.:format)'
```

We want to remove it and have routing rules explicitly. Since we have too many controllers, this task can be tedious. Is there some code analyzing tools that can aid the process of migrating from the catch-all route to specific routes?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately I'm not aware of any special tool. My suggestion is to start, controller after controller, to create a route and update all the references:

1. Switch to named routes for links
2. Write routing specs/tests
3. Use controller/integration specs/tests to validate the change

After you reviewed all the controllers, disable the route and check if the tests/specs are still passing.